# Value of Reactive Form not being set in view due to FormControlName

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have retrieved data from the database and would like to pre-set an update form with preset values. The values are preset when the FormControlName is not set in the input field the interpolation works. Once FormControlName is added it removes it. I have tried setValue and patchValue none have worked. Any suggestions of why this would be or a potential solution? thanks in advance

```
        

         ngOnInit() {
             this.currUserId = this.userId$.value;
              this.authService
            .findOne(this.currUserId)
             .pipe(map((user: User) => (this.currentUser = user)))
             .subscribe();
             }
             
            
             

                 <div class="tab-container" *ngIf="currentUser">

                  <form [formGroup]="accountForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
                   <ion-card class="personal-form">
                  <h3>Personal Details</h3>
                  <div class="form-input">
                  <label>FirstName</label>
                   <input
                  formControlName="firstName"
                  type="text"
                    value="{{currentUser.firstName }}"
                      />
                   </div>
        
                  <div class="form-input">
                   <label>surname</label>
                   <input
                   formControlName="surname"
                  type="text"
                  value="{{ currentUser.surname }}"
                />
                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>
```

Comment: if you has yet create the form, [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setValue) must work if your object has the same structure that the object you received. Else you can use [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue). But your problem is the use of "map" in your observable. why? do you know about the map operator? map rxjs operator is to transform the response of the observable **never** to execute any action. You should write your code under subscription.NOTE: exist the rxjs operator tap and some times it's used to cache or log the response, but **never** map

Comment: Thank you for this. I have refactored the code and taken pipe and map out and placed the code within the subscription I overlooked that. and was able to call patchvalue and pass the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing value in the input element, use "formBuilder".

```js
constructor(
  ...
  private _fb: FormBuilder,
){}



ngOnInit() {
  this.accountForm = this._fb.group({
      firstName: [''],
      surname: [''],
  });
  this.getCurrentUser();
}

getCurrentUser() {
      this.currUserId = this.userId$.value;
      this.authService
            .findOne(this.currUserId)
            .subscribe((user: User) => {
                 this.currentUser = user;
                 this.accountForm.patchValue(this.currentUser);
       });
  }
}
```

and remove both **value="{{currentUser.firstName }}"** form HTML.